# Use Firebase Test Lab phone authentication with Firebase UI

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui, firebase-test-lab

My app uses firebase UI and the only sign-in method is through phone verification. I´m trying the Firebase Test lab but firebase UI does not expose the UI elements to enter the phone number and the verification code during the test. I recorded a script in Android studio and uploaded it but for some reason the test failed.

The only information I found about this topic is [here](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/923) but in that case, an email sign-in was used.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Test Lab can't do phone number authentication because the devices don't have SIM cards or any sort of cellular service.  They only have wifi.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
Can´t we try with a phone number added for testing?

Comment: No, the device needs a sim card for that, and the devices have none.

Comment: I´m sorry to insist on this but, isn´t the SIM card just necessary to get the SMS with the code? and in firebase phone auth when we add a phone number for testing we can set the code used to verify that user, so we don´t need a SIM card to get that SMS..

Comment: Yes, it's necessary.

Answer (score 0):

just do a master code on the server side on some phone number,
for example:
phone number: 055-5478-455
master code: 909090
and let google have these credentials, it will serve them like email+password auth.